# SQLalchemy: double outerjoin and filter

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app with 4 sqlite models.  Items, Purchases, Sales and Invcount.  They each have itemname. Counts have data every day for each item.  Sales may not have data every day for each item.  Purchases does not have data every day for each item.  I have this query to create a table showing the daily details:

```py
result = db.session.query(Invcount, Sales, Purchases).select_from(Invcount). \
        filter(and_(Invcount.itemname == item_name, Invcount.count_time == "PM", 
        Invcount.trans_date >= weekly)). \
        outerjoin(Sales, Sales.trans_date == Invcount.trans_date). \
        filter(or_(Sales.itemname == item_name, Sales.itemname == None)). \
        outerjoin(Purchases, Purchases.trans_date == Invcount.trans_date). \
        filter(or_(Purchases.itemname == item_name, Purchases.itemname == None)). \
        order_by(Invcount.trans_date.desc()).all()
```

this is the table it produces:

| Date | Begin | Purchases | Sales | Waste | Theory | Count | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday-07/26 | 17 | + 16 | - 1 | - 0 | = 32 | - 32 | = 0 |
| Sunday-07/25 | 24 | + | - 7 | - 0 | = 17 | - 17 | = 0 |
| Saturday-07/24 | 32 | + | - 8 | - 0 | = 24 | - 24 | = 0 |

On days when there are purchases of all items and when there are no purchases of any items, the query works the way i want.
The problem is when i purchase SOME items but not others(or Sales).  Those days do not appear in the table for items which were NOT purchased, when other items were purchased.  so, for example another item, which was not purchased on monday, would display like this:

| Date | Begin | Purchases | Sales | Waste | Theory | Count | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday-07/25 | 24 | + | - 7 | - 0 | = 17 | - 17 | = 0 |
| Saturday-07/24 | 32 | + | - 8 | - 0 | = 24 | - 24 | = 0 |

I "believe" my query pulls all the counts that match the item_name, PM and in the last 7 days.  Then all Sales from the last seven days are joined then filtered by item_name or if None.  This is where the problem is since there may be sales for other items in the week, but not for the current item, so those are all dropped, along with the "Monday" count for the current item.

How can i drop those items but not drop the count from Monday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your model based on your question but it is hard without the actual models you are using.  I think maybe something else is going wrong based on your question.  It seems to work for me based on my understanding of your problem.  Maybe try to simplify the query or to build the query manually in SQL and port it back to sqlalchemy.

You can also make the query in sqlalchemy and print it before calling `.all()` and you can see the SQL is generated.

One issue is that you might be having a problem with the repetitions generated without using sum/groupby unless the Sale and Purchase entries are unique per transdate/itemname.

```py
Base = declarative_base()


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)


class Invcount(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'invcounts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    itemname = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    count_time = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    transdate = Column(Date(), default=date.today, nullable=False)
    count = Column(Integer, default=0)


class Sale(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    itemname = Column(String(100))
    transdate = Column(Date(), default=date.today, nullable=False)
    count = Column(Integer, default=0)

class Purchase(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'purchases'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    itemname = Column(String(100))
    transdate = Column(Date(), default=date.today, nullable=False)
    count = Column(Integer, default=0)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def add_entities(session, cls, itemname, transdate, count):
    # Split test data just to test outerjoin being not 1-1.
    if count != 0:
        if count % 2 == 0:
            session.add(cls(itemname=itemname, transdate=transdate, count=count/2))
            session.add(cls(itemname=itemname, transdate=transdate, count=count/2))
        else:
            session.add(cls(itemname=itemname, transdate=transdate, count=count))

with Session(engine) as session:
    itemname = 'widget'
    from datetime import date
    days = {}
    # Make test data.
    for day, count, purchase_count, sale_count  in ((24, 32, 0, -8), (25, 24, 0, -7), (26, 17, 16, -1)):
        d = date(day=day, month=7, year=2021)
        for itemname in ('widget', 'gadget'):
            session.add(Invcount(itemname=itemname, count_time='PM', transdate=d, count=count))
            add_entities(session, Sale, itemname, d, sale_count)
            add_entities(session, Purchase, itemname, d, purchase_count)

    session.commit()

    print ('without groupby/sum')
    q = session.query(
        Invcount,
        Sale,
        Purchase
    ).select_from(
        Invcount
    ).outerjoin(
        Sale,
        and_(Invcount.itemname == Sale.itemname, Invcount.transdate == Sale.transdate)
    ).outerjoin(
        Purchase,
        and_(Invcount.itemname == Purchase.itemname, Invcount.transdate == Purchase.transdate)
    ).order_by(
        Invcount.transdate.desc()
    ).filter(
        Invcount.itemname == 'widget')
    for i, s, p in q.all():
        print (i.id, i.transdate, i.itemname, s.id if s else None, p.id if p else None, i.count, s.count if s else 0, p.count if p else 0)

    print ('with groupby/sum')
    q = session.query(
        Invcount,
        func.sum(Sale.count).label('sale_count'),
        func.sum(Purchase.count).label('purchase_count'),
    ).select_from(
        Invcount
    ).outerjoin(Sale,
            and_(Invcount.itemname == Sale.itemname, Invcount.transdate == Sale.transdate)
    ).outerjoin(
        Purchase,
        and_(Invcount.itemname == Purchase.itemname, Invcount.transdate == Purchase.transdate)
    ).group_by(
        Invcount.itemname,
        Invcount.transdate
    ).order_by(
        Invcount.transdate.desc()
    ).filter(Invcount.itemname == 'widget')
    for i, s, p in q.all():
        print (i.id, i.transdate, i.itemname, i.count, s, p)


    print ('conditions in filter instead of join')
    item_name = 'widget'
    # The start of the week?
    weekly = date(day=24, year=2021, month=7)
    q = session.query(
        Invcount, Sale, Purchase
    ).select_from(
        Invcount
    ).filter(
        and_(
            Invcount.itemname == item_name,
            Invcount.transdate >= weekly)
    ).outerjoin(
        Sale,
        Sale.transdate == Invcount.transdate
    ).filter(
        or_(
            Sale.itemname == item_name,
            Sale.itemname == None)
    ).outerjoin(
        Purchase,
        Purchase.transdate == Invcount.transdate
    ).filter(
        or_(
            Purchase.itemname == item_name,
            Purchase.itemname == None)
    ).order_by(Invcount.transdate.desc())
    for (i, s, p) in q.all():
        print (i.id, i.transdate, i.itemname, s.id if s else None, p.id if p else None, i.count, s.count if s else 0, p.count if p else 0)
```

Outputs this:

```
without groupby/sum
5 2021-07-26 widget 7 1 17 -1 8
5 2021-07-26 widget 7 2 17 -1 8
3 2021-07-25 widget 5 None 24 -7 0
1 2021-07-24 widget 1 None 32 -4 0
1 2021-07-24 widget 2 None 32 -4 0
with groupby/sum
5 2021-07-26 widget 17 -2 16
3 2021-07-25 widget 24 -7 None
1 2021-07-24 widget 32 -8 None
conditions in filter instead of join
5 2021-07-26 widget 7 1 17 -1 8
5 2021-07-26 widget 7 2 17 -1 8
3 2021-07-25 widget 5 None 24 -7 0
1 2021-07-24 widget 1 None 32 -4 0
1 2021-07-24 widget 2 None 32 -4 0
```

Group by with week range

```py
    print ('with groupby/sum')
    start_of_week = date(day=24, year=2021, month=7)
    end_of_week = date(day=31, year=2021, month=7)
    q = session.query(
        Invcount,
        func.sum(Sale.count).label('sale_count'),
        func.sum(Purchase.count).label('purchase_count'),
    ).select_from(
        Invcount
    ).outerjoin(Sale,
            and_(Invcount.itemname == Sale.itemname, Invcount.transdate == Sale.transdate)
    ).outerjoin(
        Purchase,
        and_(Invcount.itemname == Purchase.itemname, Invcount.transdate == Purchase.transdate)
    ).group_by(
        Invcount.itemname,
        Invcount.transdate
    ).order_by(
        Invcount.transdate.desc()
    ).filter(
        Invcount.itemname == 'widget',
        Invcount.transdate >= start_of_week,
        Invcount.transdate < end_of_week,
    )
    for i, s, p in q.all():
        print (i.id, i.transdate, i.itemname, i.count, s, p)
```

Comment: I tried these suggestions but could not get the desired result.  I want the table to be the weeks transactions for one item.  Your models were very close.  I tried to add mine but i cannot figure out adding code so it doesn't let me save.

Comment: Seems like the middle option would be the weeks transactions ie. "with groupby/sum".

Comment: Or least the weeks transactions grouped by day.

Comment: I added a week start/end window on the transdate.

Comment: The Group_by with sum looks like its working for me.  I think maybe at first attempt i was not doing something correct but i have it working and passing all tests so far and actually helping me with a few other querys.  Thank you very much @Ian for your time on this.